# How to set up new Membership and Session providers to run in Windows Azure? Using MVC3 and Web Role

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, azure, membership-provider

I've read about the New Membership and Session providers, and the information in [this article](http://geekswithblogs.net/ranganh/archive/2011/06/21/using-the-asp.net-membership-api-wish-sql-server--sql.aspx) is that just changing the connectionStrings the database would build itself magically in my SQL Azure Database.

So, I first changed my connection to:

```
<add name="Project" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,xxxx;Database=xxxxx;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When I tried to debug my app with the emulator, I got the error:
    EFProviders require MultipleActiveResultSets=True for System.Data.SqlClient connection strings.

I researched about this error and realized that it was something related to Entity Framework. I tried to make an Entity Framework connection string with no success. In addtion, I read somewhere that SQL Azure doesn't support MultipleActiveResultSets.

So, I have 2 questions:

1. Is it true that if I run the application and register any user via website interface the Membership and Session tables, views and procedures will magically build in my SQL Azure database?
2. What am I missing to make my app run?

Detail: I didn't add any new item in Models folder. It's only AccountModels class, as it generates from MVC3 template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fortunatelly now I have the 2 answers:

1. Yes, it's true and very easy!
2. The mistake I did first time it was try to put MultipleActiveResultsSet as a new attribute in the connectionString line. The code have to be like this:

   ```
   <add name="Project" connectionString="Server=tcp:xxxxxxxx.database.windows.net,xxxx;Database=xxxxx;User     ID=xxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxx;Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;**MultipleActiveResultSets=True**" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
   ```

**Edited**

Now I found out other way to do that with AppFabric Caching for Session State. [Just follow this tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic3).